# How to remove space

Tags: rotating

How do I

- remove space between rows
- align the numbers with text
- fit the table to correct paper size and become two long tables, rather than three table on three pages

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

    \begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \centering
        \small
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                      leftmargin=*,
                      before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright,   % <---
                      after=\end{minipage},                                 % <---  
                    }
                      
    \begin{longtblr}[
    caption = { Distribution },
      label = {tab:my-table}
                    ]{%vlines,
             colspec = {@{} X[1, l, ]
                            X[3, l ] 
                            Q[c ,]  
                            Q[c, si={table-format=2.2}] 
                        @{} },
             row{1}  = {guard, font=\footnotesize\rmfamily, c},
             measure = vbox,
             rowhead=1
                    }
        \toprule
    bone    & bone 
                    & bone(\% )    
                        & bone     \\ 
        \midrule
    \scriptsize{bone \& bone}
                  &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone} 
                    &  { \scriptsize 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)}
                    &{\scriptsize {bone , bone} \\ \scriptsize {bone}}     \\ 
                   
    \scriptsize{bone}
                &{\textbf {\scriptsize\emph bone}\\{ \scriptsize bone\\ bone}\\ \textbf {\scriptsize\emph bone} \\{\scriptsize bone \\ bone \\ bone} \\ \textbf {\scriptsize \emph bone}  } 
                    &  { \scriptsize \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ \\  0 (0)} 
                     &{\scriptsize {bone , bone , bone} \\ \scriptsize {bone , bone}}
                     \\   \
                        
    \scriptsize{bone}
                & \scriptsize{bone\\ \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\ bone} 
                    &\scriptsize{ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)}      \\   \    \\  
                   
    \scriptsize{bone} 
                &\scriptsize{bone\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\ bone}
                    &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) }           \\ 
    \scriptsize{bone}
             & \scriptsize{\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\\textbf{bone}\\ bone \\ bone
             \\ \textbf {bone}
             \\ bone \\
             bone\\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone\\\textbf{bone}\\ bone\\\textbf {bone}}
                   &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0(0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)} \\   \\
              
    \scriptsize{bone }          
    &   {\scriptsize \textbf {bone} \\ bone  \\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\ bone \\ bone \\ bone \\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\ \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone }
                    &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0(0) \\ 0(0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) } \\   \\
                    
    \scriptsize{bone}
                &   {\scriptsize \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\\textbf {bone} \\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone bone\\\textbf{bone}\\ bone}
                     &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)  } \\   \\
    \scriptsize{bone} 
                &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone}
                     &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)  } \\   \\
                     
    \scriptsize {bone}
                &   {\scriptsize \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\ \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\ bone \\ bone }
                     &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0(0) } \\   \\
    \scriptsize{bone}
                &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone  \\ bone \\ bone}
                    &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0)  } \\   \\
    \scriptsize {bone}        
        &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone  \\ bone\\ bone\\ bone  }
                   &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) } \\   \\
    \scriptsize {bone} 
                &   {\scriptsize bone}
                    &\scriptsize{0 (0) } \\   \\
    \scriptsize {bone}
         &   {\scriptsize {bone} \\ bone           \\ \textbf{bone} \\ bone \\ \textbf {bone}\\ bone }
                   &\scriptsize{0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) } \\   \\
                
    \scriptsize {bone}      
        &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone  }
             &\scriptsize{0(0) \\0 (0)  } \\   \\   
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    %    \end{table}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Are the last two columns always blank?  Why?  This is a very long table, so you may need to look into that package.  It seems like your table is longer than wide, so I don't think rotating will help.

Comment: No the last two columns we will put numbers but when to check before continues we notice is it does not appear and fit , yeah there is a lot information but we cant take two tables because it classfication about somthing

Comment: (i) Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table,  (ii) your table is very long - it span three pages - so for it should be used one from  among packages for long tables, and not so wide, that its rotation will bring any benefit, (iii) what data will be in last two columns? two columns: numbers? text?

Comment: Looking some more, the main point of a table would be to compare similar data for different categories.  But your diagnoses are so long that you can't really make any such comparison.  Consequently, I think I would not use a table to display this data.  A simple list of diagnoses for each category would probably be sufficient.

Comment: You have the large space because "Soft tissue pathology lesion" is so long.  If you were laying things out by hand, what would you do?

Comment: Please only copy and paste errors from code that you have copy/pasted.  The error is complaining that `\begin{frontmatter} on line 91` is ended by `\end{flushleft} on line 119` and `\begin{abstract} on line 91` is ended by `\end{justify}`.  None of those environments are in your example.  Your question is also starting to drift from its original objective.  Please don't do that.

Comment: Any news? Is my answer of any help at your problem?

Comment: The sysop should be able to fix you account number or help you remove this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit (1):**

- As noted in my comment, your table is not so wide that need to be rotated, but is very long. Test show that it span three pages.
- Long tables had not to be encapsulated in `table` float (if it is, it will protrude bottom of page)
- Inserted tables in the second column can be replaced by `\makecell{...}` commands of `makecell` package.
- I would not use boldface text in table body.
- Does exist some demands, that text in table should be italic shape?

**Edit (2):**

- After edited question is more clear, what is the problem
- Using `tabularray` package can be its code significantly shorter and clear
- Contents in second column should be reorganized so, that each item is in own row.
- For contents of the last column (location) is not known how long is the longest text. In MWE below is considered that "Oral mucosa, Mandible, Maxilla#" is the longest one, so for the column type is used `Q[l]`. If the longest text  is longer, that I would replace it with `X[3,l]` by this enable automatically split of longer text in cells in several lines when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \small
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My huge table},
  label = {tab:my-table}
                ]{
         colspec = {@{} 
                        X[1.6, l,h]
                        X[3, l] 
                        Q[c, si={separate-uncertainty=true,
                                 table-align-uncertainty=true,
                                 table-format=2.1(3)}]
                        Q[l]    % X[3, l] 
                    @{} 
                    },
         rowsep  = 1pt,
         row{1}  = {guard, font=\small\bfseries, c},
         measure = vbox,
         rowhead=1
                }
    \toprule
Category    
    &   Diagnosis
        &   Frequency (\%)
                        &   Location                            \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    bone \& bone
    &     bone
        &   0(0)      &   bone, bone                   \\   
    &   bone
        &   0(0)      &   bone                            \\
\SetCell[r=8]{l}    bone
    &   \textbf{\textit{bone} bone}          
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   0(0)    &   bone, bone , bone     \\
    &   bone
        &   0(0)      &   bone , bone                  \\  
    &   \textbf{\textit{bone} bone}
        &   0(0)     &                                       \\
    &   bone 
        &   0(0)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   0(0)      &                                       \\ 
    &   bone 
        &   0(0)      &                                       \\    
    &   \textbf{\textit{bone} bone}   
        &   bone(0)      &                                       \\                 
    &   bone
        &   0(0)      &                                       \\
\SetCell[r=3]{l}    bone
    &   \textbf{bone}
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
       &   0(0)      &                                       \\
    &   bone 
       &    0(0)      &                                       \\
    &   bone 
       &    0(0)      &                                       \\ 
\SetCell[r=4]{l}    bone
    &   bone
       &    7(1.8)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
       &    2(0.5)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
       &    1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
       &    1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
       &    1(0.3)      &                                       \\
\SetCell[r=24]{l}    bone
    &  \textbf{bone}
       &    6(1.6)      &                                       \\
    &  bone
        &    1(0.3)     &                                       \\
    &  bone
       &    6(1.6)      &                                       \\
    &  \textbf{bone}
       &    1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &  bone
       &    6(1.6)      &                                       \\
    &  bone
       &    1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &  \textbf{bone}
       &    1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &  bone
       &    0(0)      &                                       \\
    &  bone
        &   0(0)      &                                       \\
    &  \textbf{bone}
        &   0(0)      &                                       \\
    &  bone
        &   0(0)     &                                       \\
    &  bone
       &    0(0)      &                                       \\
    &  \textbf{bone}
       &    0(0)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &    12(3.2)     &                                      \\
    &   \textbf{bone}
        &    3(7.5)      &                                      \\
\SetCell[r=12]{l}    bone
    &   \textbf{bone}
        &   3(7.5)      &                                       \\
    &   bone 
        &   35(9.2)     &                                       \\
    &   \textbf{bone}
        &   33(8.7)     &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   2(0.5)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   3(0.8)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   2(0.5)      &                                       \\
    &   bone 
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
   &   \textbf{bone} 
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   2(0.5)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   \textbf{bone}   
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   \textbf{bone} 
        &   2(0.5)      &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   12(3.2)     &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &   1(0.3)      &                                       \\
    &   \textbf{bone}   
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &               &                                       \\
    &   \textbf{bone}   
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &               &                                       \\
    &   bone
        &               &                                       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
%
%   editing of the rest of table is left to you 
%
bone}
            &   {\scriptsize \textbf {Bone}\\ bone\\ Osteonecrosis \\\textbf {bonelesions} \\\textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone\\\textbf{bone}\\ bone}
                 &0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)  } \\   \\
bone}
            &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone bone\\ bone}
                 &0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0)  } \\   \\

\scriptsize {bone}
            &   {\scriptsize \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone \\ \textbf {bone}\\ bone\\ bone\\ bone \\ bone }
                 &0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (bone) } \\   \\
bone}
            &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone  \\ bone\\ bone}
                &0 (0.0) \\ 0(0)  } \\   \\
\scriptsize {bone}
    &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone  \\ bone\\ bone\\ bone  }
               &0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) } \\   \\
\scriptsize {bone}
            &   {\scriptsize bone}
                &0 (0) } \\   \\
\scriptsize {bone}
     &   {\scriptsize {bone} \\ bone           \\ \textbf{bone} \\ bone \\ \textbf {bone}\\ bone }
               &0 (0) \\ 0 (0) \\ 0 (0) } \\   \\

\scriptsize {bone}
    &   {\scriptsize bone\\ bone  }
         &0 (0) \\0 (0)  } \\   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

When more information about your table will be known, I can extend showed table to complete table of your desired form.

Comment: Thank You! it is great , i tried and looks good but how can make table fit to paper size here look small and there space

Comment: @RMAB, continue ... Please remove your "answer" and edit your question accordingly. To it add all information information for which you were asked!

Comment: @RMAB, see edited answer.

Comment: thank you it's good now but when i copy the code and paste in my article  appears message error , the picture above

Comment: @RMAB, showed errors are not related to table. They are cause by something else. I tested my MWE on OVerlead too and it there works fine: no errors, no warnings. BTW, we haven't any information about your document, so is very hard to help you. It seems that `\begin{frontamater}` is wrong. I guess that it should be `\frontamater`.

Comment: @RMAB, BTW, you can now upvote my answer (instead to say "thank you") ;-)

Comment: i make my own code and it is good but the width not fit in page size , i cant put environment \begin{tabular} , because longtable working when i remove it , here my code

Comment: @RMAB: You seem to be asking a new question. Please revert the changes you've made and ask a new question instead, otherwise it completely nullifies any answers to the original question.